# BottomSheet Peak Height problem when Android is using gesture instead of Navigation Button

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I have a BottomSheet inside a Coordinate layout. Which works perfectly under the normal scenario. When Android is using screen gesture instead of Navigation Button there is a problem.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/episode_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black"
app:behavior_hideable="false"
app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">
```

When using Navigation button in android
[image]

When using gesture navigation

[image]

I have tried negative `app:behavior_peekHeight` but it is not working. but when I gave  `app:behavior_peekHeight="@dimen/_45sdp"` it shows player controller but also shows bottom layout. I want to hide the bottom layout.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I fixed it by using

```
bottomSheetBehavior.setGestureInsetBottomIgnored(true);
```

Comment: After 4 hours of search at last able to fix it, Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I spent 6 hours searching.

Comment: You saved my day before spending lots of hour :D Thanks.